# url-loader configuration in webpack is loading the images from different path in React JS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am working on React JS project. 
I am using a ready-made bootstrap 3 themes for the project.

I am breaking theme sections into the components.

**1) Here is my WorkWithUs.js Component.**

```
import React from 'react';

import submitRest from './../images/submit_restaurant.jpg';
import delivery from './../images/delivery.jpg';

export default () => {
    return (
        <div className="container margin_60">
            <div className="main_title margin_mobile">
                <h2 className="nomargin_top">Work with Us</h2>
                <p>
                    Cum doctus civibus efficiantur in imperdiet deterruisset.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                    <a className="box_work" href="">
                        <img src={submitRest} width="848" height="480" alt="" className="img-responsive" />
                        <h3>Submit your Restaurant<span>Start to earn customers</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut virtute fabellas vix, no pri falli eloquentiam adversarium. Ea legere labore eam. Et eum sumo ocurreret, eos ei saepe oratio omittantur, legere eligendi partiendo pro te.</p>
                        <div className="btn_1">Read more</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <a className="box_work" href="submit_driver.html">
                        <img src={delivery} width="848" height="480" alt="" className="img-responsive" />
                        <h3>We are looking for a Driver<span>Start to earn money</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut virtute fabellas vix, no pri falli eloquentiam adversarium. Ea legere labore eam. Et eum sumo ocurreret, eos ei saepe oratio omittantur, legere eligendi partiendo pro te.</p>
                        <div className="btn_1">Read more</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Above you can see, I am importing two images.

**2) Project Structure**

[image]

**3) Here is my webpack.config.js file**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isProduction = env === 'production';
    const CSSExtract = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');

    return {
        entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/app.js'],
        output: {
            path : path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: CSSExtract.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                    sourceMap: true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif|svg)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 8000,
                                name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|mp4)$/,
                    loader: "file-loader"
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            CSSExtract,
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                "window.jQuery": "jquery"
            })
        ],
        devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
            historyApiFallback: true,
            publicPath: '/dist/'
        }
    }
}
```

As I am using url-loader to process images, if the image size is greater than 8kb image will be converted and saved to the path 'pubilc/dist/images/filename.jpg'

When I run my development server, then I see that images size is more than 8kb and it is processed and stored at the location 'public/dist/images/filename.jpg'

but when I check it in the browser, I see no image is displayed. 
When I inspected the code, I saw the image path it is using is 'image/filename.jpg', which should have been the path 'public/dist/images/filename'.

Check the below screenshot.

[image]

But, if I change the image path to '/dist/images/filename.jpg' I see the image is loading perfectly fine.

Check the below screenshot.

[image]

I see that url-loader is properly processing the image and storing it to the path 'public/dist/images/filename'.But after running the server, the image path it takes is different.

Kindly help me how can I adjust the webpack settings so that this works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **webpack.config.js** file, I did this change and the images are now served from right directory.

I added **publicPath** and set it to the **/dist/**.

```
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8000,
                            name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
                            publicPath: '/dist/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify an output path instead of adding that into the `name` property.
Change this:
    `

```
    {
                        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif|svg)$/,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'url-loader',
                                options: {
                                    limit: 8000,
                                    name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },

`
```

to this:

```
`
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif|svg)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                limit: 8000,
                                name: '[hash]-[name].[ext]',
                                publicPath: 'images/'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
`
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, you were too close, Instead of outputPath, I used publicPath and images are loading now.

Comment: I did want to suggest that also, but didn't want to push ti till I was sure. I will update the answer to include that, so that other users will find a solution to this problem.